# Probability and elementary set theory proofs

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

**(i) suppose P(A) = $0 $ or $ 1$, prove that A and any subset B of Ω are independent.**

I did:  $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1 $ since $ P(Ω)=1.$

If $P(A)=0, $ then $P(B)=1-P(C)=P(B|A)$

Similarly, if $P(A)=1, $ then $P(B)=P(C)=P(B|A)$

Therefore, A and any subset B of Ω are independent. Is this correct and/or sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof on (i) doesn't seem to actually show anything.

**(I):**
If $P(A)=0$ then for any event $B$, we have $P(A\cap B)\leq P(A)$ so $P(A\cap B)=0$ and $P(A)P(B)=0$. Thus $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ so $A,B$ are independent.

If $P(A)=1$ then $P(A\cap B)=P(B)\iff P(B\setminus A)=0$. But since $B\setminus A\subset A^c$, we have $P(B\setminus A)\leq P(A^c)=0$ and the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad assumption:

$$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=1.$$

In the case $P(A) = 1,$ you cannot use this to prove something about
"any subset $B$ of $\Omega$", because the assumption implies that $P(B) = 0$.
We know there are subsets of $\Omega$ that have non-zero probabilities,
and you have discarded all of them.